# Android Verifier failure due to class length?

Tags: java, android

I'm programming my first, and admittedly amateurish, android project.  Currently I'm creating buttons inside a viewpager class but I reached a point where adding code, any code, inside the instantiateItem cause the viewpager to fail.  Even code that doesn't do anything, for example:
`int a = 1;`
causes the crash as long as it seems to be the critical line number.  The whole program runs great, and then I add one line, any code, anywhere inside instantiateItem, and it crashes.  Android build target is 4.0, min sdk is 14.  Crash occurs on both the emulator and on my galaxy nexus phone. Total length of code inside the viewpager is 1000 lines including comments and white space, with those removed it is about 850 lines.

Exact Error:

VFY: invalid switch target 26 (-> 0x9e0) at 0x9c6[1]

VFY: rejecting opcode 0x2b at 0x9c6

W/dalvikvm(8886): VFY:  rejected Lcharacter/sheet/CharacterViewer$MyPagerAdapter;.instantiateItem (Landroid/view/View;I)Ljava/lang/Object;

W/dalvikvm(8886): Verifier rejected class Lcharacter/sheet/CharacterViewer$MyPagerAdapter;

W/dalvikvm(8886): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a661f8)

E/AndroidRuntime(8886): java.lang.VerifyError: character/sheet/CharacterViewer$MyPagerAdapter

code for character viewer activity:

```
public class CharacterViewer extends Activity { 
final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);   
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pager);     
    Intent startCharacterViewer = getIntent();
    final int activePagerPage = startCharacterViewer.getIntExtra("activePagerPage", 0);
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(activePagerPage); } 

private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Intent startCharacterViewer = getIntent();
    final int activeCharacter = startCharacterViewer.getIntExtra("activeCharacter", 0);
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;          
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        db.open();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        String name = db.getAttribute(activeCharacter, 1);
        int level = Integer.valueOf(db.getAttribute(activeCharacter, 2));
        //repeats for many variables (106 total)
        db.close();
        View v = null;

        switch (position) {
        //case 0
        case 0:
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, null); 
            break;
        //case 1
        case 1:
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.features, null);
            break;
        //case 2    
        case 2:
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.summary, null); 
            TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            text1.setText (name + "    level " + level + " " + characterClass);
            //repeats many times for more text views
            //many many buttons and text views defined here
        //case 3   
        case 3: 
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.skills, null);
            //more text views and buttons defined here

        case 4:
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inventory, null);
            break;
        }



        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v, 0);


        return v;
    }
```

Buttons and text view set code are nested inside the case areas of the instantiateItem.
Example of one of the buttons:

```
            TextView hpUpdaterText1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewHP);
            TextView hpUpdaterText2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewSurges);
            final int a1 = hpMax;
            final int b1 = hpSurgeMax;
            View.OnClickListener hpModifierListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(CharacterViewer.this);
                    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.edithitpoints);
                    myDialog.setTitle("Modify Permanent Health Values");
                    myDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    myDialog.show();                    
                    EditText text1 = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextHPMax);
                    text1.setText ("" + (a1));                      
                    EditText text2 = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextSurges);
                    text2.setText ("" + (b1));
                    //Cancel button
                    Button button1 = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editHitPointsCancel);
                    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            myDialog.dismiss();
            }});
                    //OK button
                    Button button2 = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editHitPointsOK);
                    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            EditText text1 = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextHPMax);
                            String a = text1.getText().toString();
                            if( a.length() == 0 ) {text1.setError( "Value Required" );}
                            EditText text2 = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextSurges);
                            String b = text2.getText().toString();
                            if( b.length() == 0 ) {text2.setError( "Value Required" );}
                            if (a.length() != 0 && b.length() != 0){
                            db.open();
                            db.updatePermanentHP(activeCharacter, a, b);                                
                            db.close();
                            //restart activity to update variables
                            Intent startCharacterViewer = new Intent("android.intent.action.SUMMARY");
                            startCharacterViewer.putExtra("activeCharacter", activeCharacter);
                            finish();
                            startCharacterViewer.putExtra("activePagerPage", 2);
                            startActivity(startCharacterViewer);
                            myDialog.dismiss();}
                            else {Toast msg = Toast.makeText(CharacterViewer.this,
                                    "Please enter a value for" + "\n" + "all available fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    msg.show();;}
            }});
            }};
            hpUpdaterText1.setOnClickListener(hpModifierListener);
            hpUpdaterText2.setOnClickListener(hpModifierListener);
```

adding any code line anywhere as long as its inside the instantiateItem causes the error. For example I can cut and paste this block of code anywhere inside instantiateItem and it makes the program crash.  These variable names aren't used for anything.

example problem code block:

```
        int uuu = 1;
        int aaa = 2;
        int bbb = 3;
        int ccc = 4;
        int ddd = 5;
        int eee = 6;
```

Comment: Based on the error "VFY: invalid switch target", i wonder if this issue is a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025891/switch-case-statements-causes-fatal-error-in-my-android-app

Comment: Only 5 cases here so probably not the exact same problem.  That link does mention a limit on the number of views but doesnt elaborate and my googlefu isn't turning anything up.  Additional code doesn't need to be inside the cases in order to cause the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by moving all the text view and button code out of the instantiateItem method and into their own methods, and then calling those methods for each case instead of having the code directly inside instantiateItem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you're problem is not due to class length. I've seen old J2ME code 8000 lines long because they collapsed code all in to one class (for space saving reasons). Modern phones and IDE can definitely support more. Post some of your code and maybe we can help.

Comment: I added significantly more code detail including an example of a code block that I can paste anywhere inside instantiateItem and cause a crash

Answer (score 0):

A dex VRFY error message with "normal-sized" code pieces (i.e. less than 10000 lines) means that you hit a bug in either:

1. The Dalvik byte code verifier. There was a bug in the Froyo Dalvik bytecode verifier which looks similar [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11552). Do you deploy/test on Froyo?
2. A bug in the Java compiler. If the Java compiler produces incorrect Java bytecode then the Dalvik bytecode will also be incorrect. This is unlikely if you use Eclipse or javac for compilation.
3. A bug in the dexer. The dexer translates Java bytecode into Dalvik bytecode. If there is bug in the translation process incorrect Dalvik bytecode is emitted.

Comment: This was happening on android 4.0 and 4.0.3 - didn't try on anything lower before deciding to go with the workaround.